# Product of consecutive transpositions.

Tags: permutation-cycles

I was interested if this equality holds for arbitrary $n$:

$$(1 \space 2)(2\space3)(3\space 4)...(n-1\space n) (n\space 1)=(1)(2 \space 3 \space 4... \space n-1 \space n)$$

(considering multiplications are done in $S_n$)

It looks like it is true (I've done calculations for $n=2, 3, 4$ and the formula does work). But it's hard for me to prove this in general.

Comment: The RHS has a typo, doesn’t it?  Why would $1$ have a fixed point?  Especially for $n=2$.

Comment: There was a terrible bug... corrected, thank you

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes more sense.  Have you tried just tracing the orbit of each element?  It probably helps to separate into cases for $1$, $n$, and elements in between.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried. It is especially easy for $1, n$, but it is not that obvious for other elements

Comment: $1 \rightarrow n \rightarrow n-1 \rightarrow n-2 \rightarrow ... \rightarrow 1$, so $1$ remains untouched.

Comment: $n \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2$, so $n$ goes to $2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that permutations act from the left, so we apply the transpositions from right-to-left.

As the OP mentions in the comments, $1$ is a fixed point of the permutation in question.

The element $n$ follows the trajectory $n \mapsto 1 \mapsto 2$.

For any other $k$ with $1 < k < n$, element $k$ is untouched until it encounters the transposition $(k\;k+1)$, at which point it moves to $k+1$ which puts it out of reach of all other transpositions.

Hence $k \mapsto k+1$ for all such $k$.  Combining this with $n \mapsto 2$ gives
the desired cycle structure.